# How to kill a program if it runs too long

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program for school, and I have come across a problem. It is a webcrawler, and sometimes it can get stuck on a url for over 24 hours. I was wondering if there was a way to continue the while loop and go to the next url if it takes over a set amount of time. Thanks

Comment: Specify a timeout in the library you use to send your HTTP requests.

Comment: That will depend on the library you're using to grab the url. Check the documentation for some sort of timeout parameters.

Comment: The part that takes the longest is adding the list of outlinks to a dictionary. dictionary[page] = outlinks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `urllib` in Python 3 You can use the `timeout` argument in the `urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=<t in secs>)`. That parameters is used for all blocking operation used internally by `urllib`.

But if you are using a different library, consult the doc or mention in the question.

Comment: The part that takes the longest is adding the list of outlinks to a dictionary. dictionary[page] = outlinks

Comment: That is the part I am looking to kill

Comment: Just the default python dictionary.